# "'int' object is not iterable" when asking for a Number input (beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am planning to create a program which basically lists the Fibbonacci sequnce up to 10,000
My problem is that in a sample script that I wrote I keep getting the error 'int' object is not iterable
My aim is that you enter a number to start the function's loop.
If anyone would help out that would be great
P.S I am a coding noob so if you do answer please do so as if you are talking to a five year old.

Here is my code:

```
def exp(numbers):
    total = 0
    for n in numbers:
        if n < 10000:
            total = total + 1
    return total

x = int(input("Enter a number: "), 10)

exp(x)

print(exp)
```

Comment: What do you expect `for n in numbers:` to do here? `numbers` is a single integer, not a sequence. Did you want to loop over the numbers from `0` all the way up to the value given in `numbers`?

Comment: for n in numbers:  should be for n in range(0, numbers)

Comment: @learningNew: *provided* that that is what they want. That's far from clear.

Comment: yes I did want it to do that

Comment: @MartijnPieters, My bad, but at first look I assumed so.

Comment: Python uses a different kind of `for` loop than you're thinking. Also `print(exp)` wont do what you want either. You need to store the result of `exp(x)` or else use `print(exp(x))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numbers` is an int. When you enter the number 10, for example, the following happens in `exp()`:

```
for n in 10:
    ...
```

`for` loops through each element in a sequence, but `10` is not a sequence.

`range` generates a sequence of numbers, so you should use `range(numbers)` in the for loop, like the following:

```
for n in range(numbers):
    ...
```

This will iterate over the numbers from 0 to number.

Comment: Good answer, linking to the docs on `for` loops is probably a good idea in this case as the OP is so new to Python.

Comment: @VinalV Check the green check mark near the votes then. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: A heads up to the OP (and other new users): `for n in range(10)` will use `10` as an *excluded* upper bound.  I.e. the last value `n` will take on is `9`, not `10`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments, you need to define a range -- at least this is the way Python do this:

```
def exp(numbers):
    total = 0
    for n in range(0, numbers):
        if n < 10000:
            total = total + 1
    return total
```

You can adjust behavior of range a little e.g. interval is using. But this is another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct you just need to change :

```
for n in numbers:
```

should be

```
for n in range(0, numbers)
```

Since you can iterate over a sequence not an int value.

Answer (score 0):

Good going, Only some small corrections and you will be good to go.

```
def exp(numbers):
    total = 0
    for n in xrange(numbers):
        if n < 10000:
            total += 1
    return total

x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print exp(x)
```